# How can I make these .htaccess rules work together?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

For reasons beyond the scope of this question I need to have WP in the root of my domain, `example.com`. However, `example.com`is already mapped to my live site, which is actually stored in the subdirectory `example.com/livesite`. Currently I'm using .htaccess to point `Example.com` to that subdirectory; however, WP has its own set of .htaccess rules that will screw up that redirecting if I include them. The rules are necessary for WP to work, however, as I'm using a multi-site install and the subsites are inaccessible without the appropriate .htaccess rules.

The .htaccess I'm currently using:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes)|site1|site2|site3) - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/example/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /example/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ example/index.php [L]
```

The .htaccess I need to safely integrate into that one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

So far the closest I've come to getting these two to work together is the second line of the .htaccess I'm currently using; however, all that does is get me access to the admin side for the primary WP blog. The other blogs remain inaccessible.

How can I integrate these two .htaccess rules so that `example.com` still points to `example.com/livesite`, AND all WP-related URLs will pass through and return the expected pages?

Comment: If both your site and wordpress is accessed from the same host (example.com), then you can't integrate them.

Comment: @JonLin Well, Wordpress is officially as much of an unholy nightmare as I thought it was going to be. If my clients weren't using it I never would have made the switch. Thanks for the help. Guess I'll be spending the weekend rebuilding the entire site on my current CMS.

Comment: @ajw-art why don't you move the blog into a folder and keep the site on the root?

Comment: @Prix that's the way it was set up originally, and I thought that would be fine until I discovered that WP's multisite feature, which lets you manage multiple WP sites from one install, won't let you map a domain (like example2.com) to a sub-site unless WP is installed in the root. And so my nightmare began.

Comment: So basically you have the main WordPress at `/home/youraccount/public_html/` and any sub domains go into `/home/youraccount/public_html/subdomain_folder` and you want `subdomain_folder` mapped to the root folder so you can display the blog for that sub domain? If that's so it might be possible. As a side note you're better of remove all that wall of text from your question and reformat it with on the important information about what you have, what you want it to work and what you have tried.

Comment: @prix Yes, Wordpress is in 'public_html.' I'm unsure about the second half of your question, however. The problem is that WP doesn't create actual folders for any of the sites within a multisite install; if it did, I could simply point example2.com to that folder and be done. I believe WP subsites only exist within the WP database, which is why the .htaccess is needed. My main site, however, DOES exist in an actual subdirectory of 'public_html', 'mainsite'.

Comment: @ajw-art its just an experimental idea, but if you had a dedicated IP to your site, it might be possible to archive that without having to create the sub domains, basically you would only point the sub domains. I will give it a try and if that works I will post an answer. With `.htaccess` alone it would not be possible because the sub domain is tied to that given directory so you can move it backwards to other folders. Is your hosting using cPanel or similar control panel?

Comment: @Prix Yes, I have cPanel. I've got a shared IP on my account, but not a dedicated one. I don't know if this changes the answer or not, but I'll actually be converting my main site to WP in a few weeks, at which point I'll no longer need to worry about the conflict between WP and my main site. But I need WP working now because I want one of the subsites to be live ASAP, and I don't want it to appear as a subdirectory of my main site.

Comment: @ajw-art well without an dedicated IP this would not work and even with one I am not sure if it will work, like I've said above I will give it a try and if it works I will make an answer on how to do it. Will probably post back once I get home in a few hours.

Comment: if the second htaccess is the default htaccess for WP multisite using subdirectories, you just need to add en excemption for the /livesite.. the problem is i need to know what sort of urls/directories does the example.com (main site) have.. so i can exclude them

Comment: @reikyoushin the URLs for example.com are default (Home), Portfolio, About, and contact.

Comment: @ajw-art sorry on the late response, I've tried my solution with cPanel and it does not work because it uses a default `virtualhost` so the IP doesn't get passed straight if the domain is not present on it.

Comment: @ajw-art in case you're interested on testing it, here is the method: you hire a cheap plan with a dedicated IP, for example on hostgator that would cost you $8.36 with the IP (this hosting company was just an example). Then you don't create any addon domains or sub domains, but you point all the sub domains or domains to the IP you acquired via DNS, then what happens is that if the hosting does not have the default virtualhost all the domains and sub domains goes to that IP which is your domain virtualhost so it will be all on the root folder and you can easily re route within WP.

Comment: @Prix Thanks so much! I'll keep that in mind for the future. In the end I decided to rebuild the site in my original CMS, which fortunately only took a few hours as it's a small site. It's up and running smoothly now.